# Unexpected behavior with no-wrap children of table elements

Tags: html, css, layout, css-tables

I have an element that is intended to span a single line. The width of the element should be the width of the document. If the contents of the element overflow, the overflow should be clipped and replaced with ellipsis.

I wrote this CSS to accomplish that:

```
.inner {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, I did not get back the expected behavior. The text just overflowed.

When I looked maybe ten levels up the document tree I found grandparent elements styled as a `table` and `table-cell` which, even though they had explicit widths of 100% as well, wrapped around the no-wrap child.

Since, the nowrap child was using a relative width, the width was set by the table element.

Does this make sense and are there any reasonable workarounds?

Here's a jsfiddle, try commenting the tables out: https://jsfiddle.net/q3jzh085/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set `table-layout: fixed` on `table` element.

> Cells use the overflow property to determine whether to clip any overflowing content, but only if the table has a known width; otherwise, they won't overflow the cells.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.inner {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <div class="inner">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. I was reading through the documentation on table elements trying to figure out if it explicitly says tables should adjust to fit the width of their content. I believed it was in there but I though this might be a bug. It does state that on the table-layout property, with this as an example! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout